# Why can't I import my uploaded font?

Tags: css, fonts, import

how come this doesn't work? I can't seem to load the font. I have replaced my real domain name with "mydomain"...

```
@font-face {
font-family: MinionProSemiboldDisp;
src:url('http://www.mydomain.dk/fonts/MinionPro-SemiboldDisp.woff'),
    url('http://www.mydomain.dk/fonts/MinionPro-SemiboldDisp.ttf'),
    url('http://www.mydomain.dk/fonts/MinionPro-SemiboldDisp.eot'); /* IE9 */
}

h1 {
font-family: MinionProSemiboldDisp, Georgia, Times;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What browser are you using? A pretty complete description of the process is described on http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-use-cross-browser-web-fonts-part-1/ . Also, check your font name carefully! Also, check if your webserver serves the font files correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have got any errors in Console?

Small tip:
Instead of

> http://

use just

> //

It will automatically detect if you are using http or https connection.

Example:

> url('//www.mydomain.dk/fonts/MinionPro-SemiboldDisp.woff')

Answer (score 0):

I'm missing the 'format' elements

```
body {
    font-family: MinionProSemiboldDisp, Georgia, Times;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'MinionProSemiboldDisp';
  src: url('/fonts/MinionPro-SemiboldDisp');
  src: url('/fonts/MinionPro-SemiboldDisp?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('/fonts/MinionPro-SemiboldDisp.woff') format('woff'),
       url('/fonts/MinionPro-SemiboldDisp.ttf') format('truetype'),
       url('/fonts/MinionPro-SemiboldDisp.svg#MinionProSemiboldDisp') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: I have used your code, but it doesn't work. I have uploaded four different fonts (woff, svg, ttf and eot).